# What is file globbing?

Tags: linux, unix, glob

I was just wondering what is file globbing? I have never heard of it before and I couldn't find a definition when I tried looking for it online.

Comment: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/G/glob.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Globbing is the `*` and `?` and some other pattern matchers you may be familiar with.

> Globbing interprets the standard wild card characters * and ?, character lists in square brackets, and certain other special characters (such as ^ for negating the sense of a match).

When the shell sees a glob, it will perform *pathname expansion* and replace the glob with matching filenames when it invokes the program.

For an example of the `*` operator, say you want to copy all files with a `.jpg` extension in the current directory to somewhere else:

```
cp *.jpg /some/other/location
```

Here `*.jpg` is a glob pattern that matches all files ending in `.jpg` in the current directory. It's equivalent to (and much easier than) listing the current directory and typing in each file you want manually:

```
$ ls
cat.jpg dog.jpg drawing.png recipes.txt zebra.jpg

$ cp cat.jpg dog.jpg zebra.jpg /some/other/location
```

Note that it may look similar, but it is *not* the same as Regular Expressions.

You can find [more detailed information here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) and [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)