# BrowserSync only works sometimes

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync, roots-sage

**Content**

I develop websites with the [Roots](https://roots.io) stack which utilizes [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) + [BrowserSync](https://browsersync.io/).

When I execute `gulp watch`, initially, it opens up my browser to https://localhost:300X and I see the site I'm working on - as expected.

**The Goal**

When I save `CSS` (`SASS`), `HTML`, `JS` or `PHP`, Gulp compiles and BrowserSync is suppose to refresh the page.

**The Problem**

Over time (couple of months), it now almost never refreshes after saving a `PHP` file. It rarely does it for `HTML`. And as of this week it's only doing it sometimes for `CSS` / `SASS`. However, still refreshes the `JS` consistently.

Sometimes refreshing the page manually doesn't even work.

I don't know why, and I don't know how to resolve it.

**My Theory**

It seems that BrowserSync is caching or something.

**Further Context**

To clarify:

- There are no errors output in Gulp and it appears to execute correctly.
- If I have a SASS file open and save 10 times in a row. Sometimes it will be most of those times. Other times it will only be a few times.
- I **do** give it a few seconds between saves because I have seen it choke if I save to rapidly.
- This is working with **existing** files. I have not tested with creating new files.

**My Gulp.js File**

https://gist.github.com/s3w47m88/5b1511ef4f2bb3c458924642da818e9a

Comment: post your gulp config section with relevant sections (show browsersync setup. show filewatch setup)  ...also keep in mind that file watches dont naturally discover new files. If you have a basic setup, you have to stop and restart your local server to sync the browser with the new files.

Comment: I have posted my gulp.js file, but I'm not sure what you mean by "browsersync setup" and "filewatch setup".

Comment: by "browsersync setup" i meant your bs server init. by "filewatch setup" I meant where you had your file glob patterns and gulp.watch settings"  ...I'm reviewing your code to see if I can see anything for you to try

Comment: Simple first: create a new task that does nothing but execute browserSync.reload. Add that task as the last task to run in your gulp.watches.  I do manual browserSync.reload calls for all of my files and don't experience any problems you describe.

Comment: Okay, I located the BrowserSync init and respective glob (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229465/what-is-file-globbing) patterns in the gulp.js at line 256. And I added this line, a 'task', at the end of the gulp.task container: gulp.watch(browserSync.reload); - But now I'm not sure what the next step is or what to expect as the result.

Comment: `gulp.watch("app/*.php").on("change", ()=>{phpTasksYouDefined; browser.reload;});`  That's the basic pattern I follow for getting gulp to process changes and have browser sync reload after finished.

Comment: You are using gulp.start which I don't trust given its non-documented status.  Try gulp.task('default', function(callback) {

  runSequence('clean', 'build', callback)
});